# WPF ListBox - Change background color of items programmatically

Tags: wpf, listbox, background-color, listboxitem

I have something like this:

```
public class Member {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Age { get; set; }
   ...
}

List<Member> members = new List<Member>{ new Member(Id = 1, Name="Chuck", Age="32"), new Member(Id = 2, Name="Eve", Age="10")};
Listbox1.ItemsSource = members;
```

How can I change the background of items in the `ListBox`, if the age is less than 18?

Comment: By binding the ListBoxItem's Background property to Age in an ItemContainerStyle, and using an appropriate Binding Converter.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the background of a `ListBoxItem` can be done by changing the item container style. Conditional setting of the color however requires a `IValueConverter`. You can write your own for checking `Age`. Please consider making `Age` a property of type `int`, otherwise you will have to parse it on each conversion from `string`.

```
public class AgeToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return int.Parse((string)value) < 18 ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("This is a one-way conversion.");
   }
}
```

### XAML solution

In XAML you would create an instance of your converter in the resouces of the list box or any other resource dictionary. Then you would bind the `ItemsSource` to your `members` property and add a custom items container style. The style is based on the default style for the `ListBoxItem`. In it you bind the `Background` property to `Age` with your custom converter, which will convert the age string to a solid color brush.

```
<ListBox x:Name="Listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding members}">
   <ListBox.Resources>
      <local:AgeToColorConverter x:Key="AgeToColorConverter"/>
   </ListBox.Resources>
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Age, Converter={StaticResource AgeToColorConverter}}"/>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

### Code-Behind solution

Suppose you defined your list box in XAML like this.

```
<ListBox x:Name="Listbox1"/>
```

Then the same as for the XAML solution applies to this code, except for we create the converter as a local variable and the items source is directly assigned instead of a binding.

```
var ageToColorConverter = new AgeToColorConverter();
var baseItemContainerStyle = (Style)FindResource(typeof(ListBoxItem));
var itemContainerStyle = new Style(typeof(ListBoxItem), baseItemContainerStyle);
var backgroundSetter = new Setter(BackgroundProperty, new Binding("Age") { Converter = ageToColorConverter });

itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(backgroundSetter);

Listbox1.ItemContainerStyle = itemContainerStyle;
Listbox1.ItemsSource = members;
```